# setTime() replacement in php

Tags: javascript, php

I want to convert below javascript code to PHP

```
<script>    
     noon = new Date();
     alert(noon);
     noon.setTime(1641951202187.3433);
     alert(noon);   
</script>
```

returning value  Wed Jan 12 2022 07:03:22 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

As in javascript `setTime()` function  Add 1641951202187.3433 milliseconds to January 1, 1970.
But i am unable to find such function in php or solution

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php

Comment: [`DateTime::setTimestamp`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimestamp.php)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72073375/php-settime-return-type-not-compatible-but-settime-in-datetime-class-has-no

Comment: `strtotime()` and `data()`

Comment: Not a lot of research went into this question, it would appear. Hence why its been badly down voted. See [ask] for guidance in future.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to convert milliseconds to seconds and then use the date() function with the following format:

```
$mili = 1641951202187.3433;
$sec = $mili /1000;
echo date('M-m-Y H:i:s',$sec);
```